# Resizing an image automatically with browser width but keeping the same height inside a div?

Tags: html, css, image, overflow

I'm trying to figure out if there is a CSS-only way to get the effect on boilerroom.tv header.  A very similar question to: [How to resize image automatically on browser width resize but keep same height?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17324928/how-to-resize-image-automatically-on-browser-width-resize-but-keep-same-height) but without filling up the entire page, only inside a div.  Basically the width stays the same as the browser and the height stays constant (say...300px) so the image get bigger and smaller but hide its overflow of the div.  thanks!

Comment: You need to post some code buddy. What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You should post code so we can get a better idea of what you're trying to accomplish and what you've tried. However, it sounds like you're looking background cover. In your CSS:

```
.element{
    background: url(path/to/image)
    background-size: cover;
    height: 300px;
    width: 100%;
}
```

Be sure to include the correct vendor prefixes for background-size for cross-browser compatibility.

Answer (score 0):

please try this one.
div{
    background: url(imagepath)
    background-size: cover;
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
}